What are some good discussion forums on cryptography?
I'm thinking of forums where you can have longer discussions and debates of the kind that are not typically allowed on a Q&A site like this.

Also there's always the elephant in the room: /r/crypto (although I can't vouch for its quality).

There is always sci.crypt.

But you need a strong mental filter to filter out the trash. That's the good thing about the up/down and close votes.

@MaartenBodewes, no kidding. I use to read sci.crypt often, but got sick of all the cranks.

It's not a forum, but there is always The Side Channel. 
You're free to present discussion pieces and ask arbitrary questions there. 
The sort of stuff that makes bad questions for the main site can make great conversation material for the sites chat room.
